# XCode 8 playground execution failed, Couldn't lookup symbols

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have just downloaded and installed the new version of XCode on my mac from the mac app store. My mac also has the latest software installed on it. I had the previous versions of xcode and they all seemed to work fine. There is something with this particular XCode that is causing the problem. So when opening up playground I get this long error which I will post below

also a good thing to note is the playground loads for about 10 minutes before showing this error

Here is the error:

```
    Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDarwin
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreImage
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUIKit
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftObjectiveC
  _playground_log_hidden
  _playground_logger_initialize
  __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftQuartzCore

* thread #1: tid = 0x10832a, 0x00000001020093c0 anotherone`executePlayground, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2
  * frame #0: 0x00000001020093c0 anotherone`executePlayground
    frame #1: 0x00000001020089c0 anotherone`__37-[XCPAppDelegate enqueueRunLoopBlock]_block_invoke + 32
    frame #2: 0x0000000102b246ac CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    frame #3: 0x0000000102b096f4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356
    frame #4: 0x0000000102b08e65 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 901
    frame #5: 0x0000000102b08884 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    frame #6: 0x0000000108035a6f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #7: 0x00000001036b6c68 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
    frame #8: 0x00000001020086e9 anotherone`main + 201
    frame #9: 0x000000010592368d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #10: 0x000000010592368d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237298/xcode-8-strange-playground-error-couldnt-lookup-symbols This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code too?

The problem might be you added a view and forgot to add it as a subview of its right mother view.

As an example: [XCode 8 strange Playground error, Couldn't Lookup Symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237298/xcode-8-strange-playground-error-couldnt-lookup-symbols). The question asker here added a text field but didn't add it as a subview of the `liveView` at the time. This question is a little similar to yours.

Hope I can help further. Cheers,
Theo